# SOAPUI SSL Self Signed Certs

Tags: ssl, soapui

I would like to use SOAPUI for creating some Web TestCase scenarios.

I am connecting to a website on my localmachine which has a self signed SSL Cert.
I have followed the following steps

http://geekswithblogs.net/gvdmaaden/archive/2011/02/24/how-to-configure-soapui-with-client-certificate-authentication.aspx

In order to export and import the certs and make a configuration change to soapUI-3.6.1.vmoptions

Comment: What's your actual question?